# html5 canvas rotate function inside of object not working

Tags: javascript, function, object, rotation, html5-canvas

I am trying to get the spin function to work with an instance of a ball i have created below.
i cant access the spin function from ball1 for some reason.
If ive tested logging to the console from the spin function and it is working but i cant figure out how to get get the ball rotating.
i had it working in earlier versions but not not fully.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please see below for my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <hmtl>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Canvas</title>

        <style type="text/css">
        canvas{
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
        </style>

      </head>

      <body>
        <canvas id="canvasOne" ></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Gets a handle to the element with id canvasOne.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");

            // Set the canvas up for drawing in 2D.
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

            canvas.width  = 500;
            canvas.height = 500;

    function Ball(xpos, ypos, r) {
      this.xpos = xpos;
      this.ypos = ypos;
      this.r = r;
      this.move = function(addx, addy) {
        this.xpos = this.xpos + addx;
        this.ypos = this.ypos + addy;
      };
      this.resize = function(setr) {
        this.r = setr;
      };
      this.draw = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(this.xpos, this.ypos);
          ctx.arc(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.r, i * (2 * Math.PI / 7), (i + 1) * (2 * Math.PI / 7));
          ctx.lineWidth = 2;
          ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.xpos, this.ypos);
        ctx.arc(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.r - 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.stroke();
      };
      this.spin = function() {
            var angle = 0;
        this.angle = (this.angle + 1) % 360;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.save();

            ctx.translate(this.xpos,this.ypos);
            ctx.rotate( this.angle*Math.PI/180 ); 
            ctx.translate(-this.xpos,-this.ypos);

            ctx.beginPath();
            this.draw();


            ctx.restore();
      };
      this.contains = function(x, y) {
        this.x = this.x;
        this.y = this.y;
        if (Math.sqrt((x - this.xpos) * (x - this.xpos) + (y - this.ypos) * (y - this.ypos)) <= this.r) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      };
      //put "ball" as a paremeter
      //ball will be the foreign Ball to test intersection against
      this.intersect = function(ball) {
        var productX = this.xpos - ball.xpos;
        var productY = this.ypos - ball.ypos;
        var distance = Math.sqrt(productX * productX + productY * productY);
        if (distance <= (this.r + ball.r)) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      };
    }
    var ball1 = new Ball(100, 100, 100);
    ball1.draw();
    ball1.spin();
    setInterval(ball1.spin,100);



        </script>

      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message when trying to call ball1.spin?

Comment: It says this.draw  is not a function. It's in reference to this.spin function.

Comment: Do you have the code anywhere online like jsfiddle or codepen that I could see it on?